# Is there a way to move test suite/cases from MTM application to Azure Devops' Test plan?

Tags: testing, testcase

We are currently using MTM (application, not web) to house our test cases.  We are moving to Azure Devops >Test Plans.  We would like to export from MTM and import into ADO.  Is there an easy way of doing this? I can not find a lot of info on this subject any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all the test cases from MTM to ADO then you can make use of Excel sheet for this bulk update.

In Excel sheet

-->Team tab

-->New List

-->Click on Servers

-->Add Your organization URL.

Select the project and add all your test cases to given table .

After adding all the test cases **save** it and again go to team tab .

Click on publish and in your ADO you can refresh and see the new test cases added over there .

For more details see this youtube video [Click Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvmJUkSiq4A)